# HTML Table values need to act as header in powerhsell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to generate the report using PowerShell for list of services in list of computers. I'm able to generate the report but it was not what i expected.

Here is my code:

```
    param ([string[]] $ServerPath,
[string[]] $ServicePath,
[string] $ENVName,
[string] $DataPath,
$csv=@()

)
$ServiceReport= "D:\Test\ServiceReport.htm" 
New-Item -ItemType file $ServiceReport -Force 
# Function to write the HTML Header to the file 
Function writeHtmlHeader 
{ 
param($ServiceReport) 
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd') 
Add-Content $ServiceReport "<html>" 
Add-Content $ServiceReport "<head>" 
Add-Content $ServiceReport "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>" 
Add-Content $ServiceReport '<title>Service Status Report </title>' 
add-content $ServiceReport '<STYLE TYPE="text/css">' 
add-content $ServiceReport  "<!--" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "td {" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "font-family: Tahoma;" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "font-size: 11px;" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "border-top: 1px solid #999999;" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "border-right: 1px solid #999999;" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "border-left: 1px solid #999999;" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "padding-top: 0px;" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "padding-right: 0px;" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "padding-bottom: 0px;" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "padding-left: 0px;" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "}" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "body {" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "margin-left: 5px;" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "margin-top: 5px;" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "margin-right: 0px;" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "margin-bottom: 10px;" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "table {" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "border: thin solid #000000;" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "}" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "-->" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "</style>" 
Add-Content $ServiceReport "</head>" 
Add-Content $ServiceReport "<body>" 

add-content $ServiceReport  "<table width='100%'>" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "<tr bgcolor='#0000FF'>" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "<td colspan='4' height='25' align='center'>" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "<font face='tahoma' color='#7CFC00' size='4'><strong>Service Stauts Report - $date</strong></font>" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "</td>" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "</tr>" 
add-content $ServiceReport  "</table>" 

} 
# Function to write the HTML Header to the file 
Function writeTableHeader 
{ 
param($ServiceReport ,$ServerName) 

Add-Content $ServiceReport "<tr bgcolor='#20B2AA'>" 
Add-Content $ServiceReport "<td width='10%' align='center'><font face='tahoma' color='#7CFC00' size='4'>Service Name</font></td>" 
Add-Content $ServiceReport "<td width='30%' align='center'><font face='tahoma' color='#7CFC00' size='4'>$ServerName</font></td>" 
#Add-Content $ServiceReport "<td width='10%' align='center'><font face='tahoma' color='#7CFC00' size='4'>Status</font></td>" 
Add-Content $ServiceReport "</tr>" 
} 

Function writeHtmlFooter 
{ 
param($ServiceReport) 

Add-Content $ServiceReport "</body>" 
Add-Content $ServiceReport "</html>" 
} 

Function WriteServiceInfo
{
param($ServiceReport ,$Servicename,$Status)
Add-Content $ServiceReport "<tr bgcolor='#008B8B'>" 
 Add-Content $ServiceReport "<td bgcolor='#F0FFF0' align=left ><b><font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='3'>$Servicename</font></td>"  
 #Add-Content $ServiceReport "<td bgcolor='#F0FFF0' align=left ><b><font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='3'>$Servername</font></td>" 
 Add-Content $ServiceReport "<td bgcolor='#F0FFF0' align=center ><b><font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='4'>$Status</font></td>" 
 Add-Content $ServiceReport "</tr>"

}


writeHtmlHeader $ServiceReport 
 Add-Content $ServiceReport "<table width='100%'><tbody>" 
 Add-Content $ServiceReport "<tr bgcolor='#008B8B'>" 
 Add-Content $ServiceReport "<td width='100%' align='center' colSpan=3><font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='6'><strong> Service Status Report</strong></font></td>" 
 Add-Content $ServiceReport "</tr>" 

 writeTableHeader $ServiceReport 


# import the CSV to get server list
$Serverlist = Import-Csv -path $ServerPath #|  Where-Object {$_.IsActive -eq '1'}
$servers=$ServerList.ServerName
$ENV=$ServerList.ENV


 # fetch the serverlist where service name match in the CSV 

 $ENVServer= (Import-Csv -path $ServerPath |  Where-Object {$_.ENV -eq $ENVName}).ServerName
  $ServicesList=(Import-Csv -Path $ServicePath).ServiceName
  foreach($Server in $ENVServer){ 
 $ServicesList=(Import-Csv -Path $ServicePath).ServiceName
 ForEach($Service in $Serviceslist){
$servicestatus=Get-Service -ComputerName $Server | Where-Object {$_.ServiceName -like "$Service"}
$lenth=$servicestatus.length
#$state=$servicestatus.Status
if ($lenth -eq 0)
{
#do nothing
}
else {
writeTableHeader $ServiceReport $servicestatus.MachineName
WriteServiceInfo $ServiceReport $servicestatus.ServiceName $servicestatus.Status
}
  }
  }
```

**Output:**

```
Service Name Server Name  Status
==================================
Service1      Server1     running
service2      server1     stopped
service1      server2     stoppped
```

**Expected Output:**

```
ServiceName   Server1 server2 server3 .........
================================================
Service1       runing  stopped running
ervice2        stopped running stopped
service3       running stopped stopped
......          ......  .....  .....
.......
```

Can you please help me if there is any chances like above. I've been trying but no luck from my side.

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: Please post code.

Comment: i've updated my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for something like this.

uncomment the <#-ComputerName $Computer#> part to make it come alive ;)
It was for testing on my own machine.

```
$Servicelist = @("WinRM", "Winmgmt", "DHCP")
$Computerlist = @("LocalHost", "Server1","Server2","Server3")

$ServiceStatus = @{}

Foreach ($Computer in $Computerlist)
{
    $ServicesFound = Get-Service <#-ComputerName $Computer#> | Where-Object {$Servicelist -contains $_.Name} | Select Name, Status

    Foreach ($Service in $ServicesFound)
    {
        If(!($ServiceStatus["$($Service.Name)"])) {
            $ServiceStatus["$($Service.Name)"] = $Service | Select @{N='Service'; E={$($Service.Name)}}, @{N="$Computer"; E={$Service.Status}}
        } else {
            $ServiceStatus["$($Service.Name)"] = $ServiceStatus["$($Service.Name)"] | Select *, @{N="$Computer"; E={$Service.Status}}
        }
    }
}

$ServiceStatus.Values | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

HTML Output

```
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Service</th><th>LocalHost</th><th>Server1</th><th>Server2</th><th>Server3</th></tr>
<tr><td>Dhcp</td><td>Running</td><td>Running</td><td>Running</td><td>Running</td></tr>
<tr><td>WinRM</td><td>Stopped</td><td>Stopped</td><td>Stopped</td><td>Stopped</td></tr>
<tr><td>Winmgmt</td><td>Running</td><td>Running</td><td>Running</td><td>Running</td></tr>
</table>
```

It looks like this

```
Service LocalHost Server1 Server2 Server3
=========================================
Dhcp    Running   Running Running Running
WinRM   Stopped   Stopped Stopped Stopped
Winmgmt Running   Running Running Running
```

Comment: thank you for your post. I've achieved the above result in different format that was good. But looking for consolidate services list and servers need to be in header of each subsequent columns then result associated under machine name against respective services.

Comment: The HTML output shows what you wanted for all i known, de server names are in the headers of the table it looks like your 'Expected Output' ignore the Object Output, pls check my code again or clarify the question.

Answer (score -1):

The only advice to give at this point is to explore Format-Table, most any commands that return some result in powershell can be piped to a format-table like shown below

```
get-process | Format-Table
```

Here is a link that provides extensive information when it comes to formatting tables in a specific way to view your results

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table

Comment: Please see my code as i'm trying for different set of services in different set of servers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16790729)

Comment: @kdopen , i wondered about your comment.  what  clarification that you are expecting from me?. could you please brief me.